# A word for the hatred of others

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Looking for a word that describes a person who disliked other humans.A misogynist hates women, what do we call someone who dislikes people in general?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I strongly recommend you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for guidance on writing strong questions, and in particular our guidance for [single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Answer (score 1):

The word you are looking for is ***misanthropist*** or ***misanthrope***. [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/misanthropist) gives your definition directly; [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/misanthrope) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misanthrope) link the word to ***misanthrope***.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was blocked from consciousness for days.

Comment: If this solves your issue, please _accept_ the answer by clicking the checkmark under the voting arrows. You get a slight boost in reputation from it, and it shows that the answer was satisfactory and useful to you. (It also gives me a boost in reputation, which is nice, but not the primary reason for accepting answers.)